# Compiling a unix make file for windows

Tags: python, c, unix, gcc

I have a c-program which includes a make file that works fine on unix systems. Although I would like to compile the program for windows using this make file, how can i go around doing that?

Additionally I have python scripts that call this c-program using ctypes, I don't imagine I will have to much of an issue getting ctypes working on windows but i heard its possible to include all the python and c scripts in one .exe for windows, has anyone heard of that?

Comment: You are probably thinking of py2exe https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2exe/

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your first paragraph: Use `MinGW` for the compiler (google it, there is a `-w64` version if you need that) and `MSYS` for a minimal environment including shell tools the `Makefile` could need.

Comment: ok nice i will try this later, does MinGW include all the basic things like math.h ?

Comment: Note: The `-w64` doesn't mean it's 64-bit only. [It's also better than the original MinGW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW#MinGW-w64).

Comment: If your c-program is simple enough, it should work immediately. You could get into trouble if you have Unix specific calls like termios to process tty io.